# Should gold badge holders really be able to unilaterally reopen their own questions that are closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, dupehammer

[An example of what I'm talking about (deleted).](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48892696/5515060)<sup>1</sup>

Screenshot of the relevant parts of the timeline for users <10k:
[image: Screenshot of the timeline]

I've got the feeling that this should not be possible. As the OP, I'm clearly biased, but why should I be able to unilaterally reopen my question that was closed as a duplicate if I have the gold badge in a relevant tag?

---

<sup>[1]: Please note that I'm **not** asking why my question was closed. The linked question is used solely as an example.</sup>

Comment: Worth noting you can only unilaterally reopen it if it's closed as a duplicate, *not* if it's due to any other reason. I do, however, agree that you *should* not be able to do so, and that reopening it could be considered "abuse" of the system.

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a breakdown in what the system *is*. Gold badge holders are *supposed* to be an expect in the tag and thus know the ins and outs of duplicates\*. Thus they are supposed to also know if their question is a duplicate or not. Therefore, being allowed to unilaterally open their own question seems in-line with the expectation. If they are *not* allowed, then the entire dupehammer expectation is wrong.  \*Note that there is no actual link between gold badge and knowing about duplicates. But that's the assumption which the system is built around.

Comment: @VLAZ I kind of agree. With great power comes great responsibility. Still it still feels weird, that I can undo the votes of up to three other people, which were sure that the linked duplicate answers my question.

Comment: @Lino ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ is it not more weird to be an expert in the field (according to the system) thus trusted to *know* the linked duplicate is wrong and not be able to do anything about it? If so, you shouldn't be trusted with a dupehammer anywhere. What if you reopen a question that's not your own where three users agreed was a duplicate? If you're not to be trusted around your own question - what makes you more trustworthy around somebody else's? The point here is that the dupehammer has to work consistently. Otherwise nobody would be worthy of it. Because it's a mess.

Comment: That's without even discussing the fact that the winning strategy to get a dupe hammer the easiest is to avoid closing as duplicates. Which...is another beef I have with the feature.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can only close/reopen the same question once. So you wont be able to reopen it again if it is closed again by other users.

Comment: @Ivar with the small caveat that you *can* but not immediately. You need to wait for the vote to expire. Which is something like 4-6 weeks IIRC. It's a lot. At least a month. But most of the time, I'd expect users would not bother waiting for that long if a closure -> dupehammer reopen -> closure happens.

Comment: @VLAZ are you sure? From my experience, I cannot re-close a question another time as Gold badge owner if it's reopened

Comment: @TemaniAfif re-closing works the same. You still need to wait out the expiration of your old vote. It's yet another of those opaque system which requires a minor in SE arcana. I'll try to find where it's described. I've had to refer to it multiple times myself...

Comment: @VLAZ I just found a very old question (2018) to re-close it again but I am not able to do.

Comment: @TemaniAfif was it reopened recently? Or a long time ago? I might be misremebering the exact arcane rules around close votes.

Comment: @VLAZ all the actions are made long time ago (somewhere in 2018)

Comment: @TemaniAfif OK, then it turns out my minor in SE arcana was not enough. I guess it doesn't work that way. There is a thing with vote ageing out but apparently it's only if you *retract* a vote. If a post has been closed/opened with your vote, you're indeed blocked from further votes in order to discourage close/open wars.

Comment: vote aging only happens if the vote didn't result in an action occuring.

Comment: @cigien: I'd conjecture that these questions are related, but this one has a slightly different texture.  The one you link to talks about the justification of using it when *others* have dupe-closed it.  This one talks about doing this at all, and the example has zero contention from anyone else around.

Comment: @Makoto I don't follow. The suggested target is also talking about a question that was closed by users other than the OP, just like this post is talking about. By contention, do you mean no one feels that the question linked in this post should actually be reopened? That's true, but quite obviously the OP is referring to cases where there *is* disagreement about whether the question should be closed. I doubt the OP is asking whether it's OK to reopen a duplicate *just* because they can.

Comment: @cigien:  The texture feels different to me.  I feel like this question is a reasonable answer in the sentiment of "why they're allowed to do this at all" versus "why they're allowed to do this during a dupe dispute".

Comment: Say that for every 10 people with a gold badge, 1 of them is an evil villain who abuses their privileges. Is that a problem? Probably not. Both people and software have gotten quite good at spotting the rotters. I feel quite alright just having blind faith in ambiguous statistics such as badges to grant people elevated janitorial privileges, more so than reputation points anyway. I simply choose to not have these kind of feelings, not about Stack Overflow. It'll live.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I really don't see an issue with this.

The system is built around trust (since it doesn't have a good technical way of enforcing compliance).  As a gold-badge holder in Java, you've (in practice) participated in enough Java questions such that you can (in theory) make a reasonable, level-headed decision on whether or not a question closed as a duplicate with that tag is or is not a dupe.

It shouldn't really matter if it's your own question.  I mean, people get dupe targets wrong all the time and that can spill into a close war, but that's when it makes sense to get diamond mods involved to sort that mess out.

So I'm going to state that this isn't really a problem unless someone sees an active pattern of abuse, and that's when diamond mods need to get involved.

Comment: You can also only do it once per question, so if it's really a dupe, you can't repeatedly hammer it back open.